# keras Wrappers for the Scikit-Learn API

Tags: scikit-learn, keras, sklearn-pandas

I want to use **AdaBoostClassifier** on **CNN**. I created a function called `create_model` that define my model and compile it. The function return the compiled **CNN**. Then I use **KerasClassifier**:

```
model = KerasClassifier(build_fn=create_model, epochs=2, batch_size=128, verbose=0, sample_weight=None)
bdt_discrete = AdaBoostClassifier( model, n_estimators=2, learning_rate=1.5, algorithm=”SAMME”)
bdt_discrete.fit(X_train, y_train, sample_weight=None)
```

It gives the following **error**:

```
ValueError: KerasClassifier doesn’t support sample_weight.
```

Is there any solutions for the error:

```
File “/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/spyder/utils/site/sitecustomize.py”, line 688, in runfile
execfile(filename, namespace)

File “/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/spyder/utils/site/sitecustomize.py”, line 93, in execfile
builtins.execfile(filename, *where)

File “~adaboost_CNN3.py”, line 251, in
bdt_discrete.fit(X_train, y_train, sample_weight=None)

File “/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sklearn/ensemble/weight_boosting.py”, line 413, in fit
return super(AdaBoostClassifier, self).fit(X, y, sample_weight)

File “/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sklearn/ensemble/weight_boosting.py”, line 130, in fit
self._validate_estimator()

File “/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sklearn/ensemble/weight_boosting.py”, line 431, in validate_estimator
% self.base_estimator.class.name)

ValueError: KerasClassifier doesn’t support sample_weight.
```

Please let me know if there are any advice.

Comment: Can you try removing the `sample_weight` from `fit()`. Just use `bdt_discrete.fit(X_train, y_train)`. You are not using any values for it anyways.

Comment: I use bdt_discrete.fit(X_train, y_train), And again get the sam error: 
  ValueError: KerasClassifier doesn't support sample_weight.

Comment: It looks like an error from AdaboostClassifier: https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/1752

Comment: Hi have commented on your issue on github. Please look at it: https://github.com/fchollet/keras/issues/8448

Answer (score 1):

For anyone dealing with this issue now, according to the [source code](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/wrappers/scikit_learn.py#L347) the KerasClassifier, KerasRegressor classes packaged with tensorflow are now deprecated.

The official recommendation is to instead use https://github.com/adriangb/scikeras